# How to use CIContext without SoftwareRenderer to render a CIFilter to avoid memory leak?

Tags: ios, memory-leaks, core-image, cifilter, ciimage

All I want to do is to avoid the `CIContext` memory leak by not using software-renderer. Therefore I want to use this:

```
CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:@{kCIContextUseSoftwareRenderer: @NO}];
```

This link https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/17142 has described its usage for scaling but not for applying `CIFilter`s. How can I do it?

My code as an example:

```
 __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
@autoreleasepool{
    weakSelf.context =[CIContext contextWithOptions:@{kCIContextUseSoftwareRenderer:@NO}];
    weakSelf.myCIFilter =[CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIComicEffect"
                            withInputParameters:@{@"inputImage":weakSelf.myCIImage}];
    weakSelf.resultCIImage =[weakSelf.myCIFilter valueForKey:kCIOutputImageKey];
    weakSelf.croppingCIImage =[weakSelf.resultCIImage imageByCroppingToRect:CGRectMake(0,0, weakSelf.affineClampImage.size.width*scale, weakSelf.affineClampImage.size.height*scale)];
    weakSelf.myCGImage =[weakSelf.myCIContext createCGImage:weakSelf.croppingCIImage fromRect:[weakSelf.myCIImage extent]];
    UIImage * renderedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:weakSelf.myCGImage];
}
```

Comment: I have a few iOS apps the use a `GLKView` and it's *single* `CIContext`, rendering filter changes in real-time. No memory leaks. If you *have* memory leaks, look into how you are using your CIContext.

Comment: Thank you, I thought GLKView is used for applying filters on camera previews or videos, so it can be used on images too? Is there an efficient way to use it than you do?

Comment: The native image type for a `GLKView.image` is a `CIImage`. The other advantage for it is that it uses the GPU unlike `UIKit`. What I do is (a) instantiate a subclassed version of it and can be treated just like a `UIImageView` that is set for aspect fit, (b) changing the image as a `CIFilter` change,  and (c) yielding a `UIImage` when asked - but only when asked. It's based on an old blog - https://www.objc.io/issues/21-camera-and-photos/core-image-intro/ - and it's repo - https://github.com/objcio/issue-21-core-image-explorer/blob/master/Core%20Image%20Explorer/FilteredImageView.swift -

Comment: (cont.) this repo's subclass contains code for other content modes and is written in (I believe) Swift 2) but my subclass has been updated to Swift 4. Since the input to a `GLKView` is a `CIImage` and my subclassed view can (1) give a `UIImage` on demand and (2) has a "self-contained" context, it may be a good solution for you. I'll post an answer with it if you wish.

Comment: Great! thank you so much, I will try this. @dfd